# Cannot run Terraform tests in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, terraform

I'm trying to run a terraform test in Jenkins.
Here's what I have done:

- Installed terraform plugin
- Added a terraform installation in global tools
- Added a freestyle project.
- In build environment I added terraform
- In build I added "execute shell" with the following commands: pwd, ls
  -la, terraform init

Whenever I try to run this build I get the following:

```
Building in workspace /Users/david.bien/.jenkins/workspace/terraform


> git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/killabien/terra.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/killabien/terra.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/killabien/terra.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision d1be254f44ab29acd0a5eb6cab06db0e78b21ff5 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f d1be254f44ab29acd0a5eb6cab06db0e78b21ff5
Commit message: "removed jenkins file"
 > git rev-list --no-walk d1be254f44ab29acd0a5eb6cab06db0e78b21ff5 # timeout=10
[terraform-plugin] $ /Users/david.bien/.jenkins/tools/org.jenkinsci.plugins.terraform.TerraformInstallation/terraform/terraform get
[terraform] $ /bin/sh -xe /var/folders/71/nc43yr_d4gj3z96vsnhf6xrc0000gn/T/jenkins7852414313721362731.sh
+ pwd
/Users/david.bien/.jenkins/workspace/terraform
+ ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x   7 david.bien  staff  238 Apr  6 12:53 .
drwxr-xr-x   5 david.bien  staff  170 Apr  6 12:50 ..
drwxr-xr-x  12 david.bien  staff  408 Apr  6 13:05 .git
drwxr-xr-x   4 david.bien  staff  136 Apr  6 12:50 .terraform
-rw-r--r--   1 david.bien  staff  242 Apr  6 12:50 main.tf
drwxr-xr-x   4 david.bien  staff  136 Apr  6 12:50 modules
drwxr-xr-x   5 david.bien  staff  170 Apr  6 13:05 terraform-plugin
+ terraform init
/var/folders/71/nc43yr_d4gj3z96vsnhf6xrc0000gn/T/jenkins7852414313721362731.sh: line 4: terraform: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I understand that it doesn't see the terraform but how else can I make it see it? I'm using a github repo for the source. I want to make a step for each terraform command: init, plan and apply. How can I achieve this is Jenkins? I couldn't find any tutorial explaining this bit.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your build environment you need to find out where terraform is installed and ensure that is on the path.  If not you need to add the directory to the agent path on Jenkins.

Comment: But isn't the terraform plugin supposed to provide that? I'm asking since I'm not sure how to use the plugin with files pulled from git.

Comment: Ok, got this. I thought this would be done automatically but I was wrong. I added the file to PATH and now it's working. Cheers.

Comment: @davidb: I added terraform.exe file itslef in BitBucket where my Jenkinsfile is present and then created the JenkinsJob but getting "terraform: command not found error". Could you please suggest how to move forward.